# Confusion regarding the proof of Open Mapping Theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis

**Background:** I was reading a response regarding the proof of open mapping theorem using the maximum modulus principle: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1213737

**Question:** I'm not too sure why is it valid to have $t > 0$ so that $\overline{D_t(z_0)} \subset U$ with $f(z) \neq w_0$ for any $z \in \overline{D_t(z_0)}$ other than $z_0$. How do we know such a $t$ exist? Can anybody explain this to me? Thank you.

Comment: The zeroes of the (holomorphic) function $f(z) - w_0$ are isolated. So we can choose a small enough disk around $z_0$ such that no other zeroes of $f(z) - w_0$ are contained in the disk.